# asymptotic behaviour of inverse hyperbolic sine function

Tags: limits

Good evening everyone,

I'm solving a physics problem and I would like to approximate the funcion arcsinh(ax)/x to a easier to work with function in the x>> region.

I did a Taylor series to approximate the x<< region, but now I don't know what to do

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\displaystyle\mathrm{arcsinh}\left(ax\right) = \ln\left(ax + \,\sqrt{\,{\left(ax\right)^{2} + 1}\,}\,\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

As you inverse hyperbolic functions are logarithmic functions.

for example,  $$ \sinh^{-1} ax = \ln|ax+\sqrt {a^2x^2 +1}|$$

so you may use that function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ais said in comments and answer, assuming $a>0$, let $y=ax$ to make
$$\frac{\sinh ^{-1}(a x)}{x}=\frac a y \frac{\sinh ^{-1}(y)}{y}=\frac a y\log\left(y+\sqrt{1+y^2}\right)$$

Now $$\log\left(y+\sqrt{1+y^2}\right)=\log(y)+\log \left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{y^2}}\right)$$ and use Taylor
$$\sqrt{1+t}=1+\frac{t}{2}-\frac{t^2}{8}+\frac{t^3}{16}-\frac{5 t^4}{128}+O\left(t^5\right)$$
$$1+\sqrt{1+t}=2+\frac{t}{2}-\frac{t^2}{8}+\frac{t^3}{16}-\frac{5 t^4}{128}+O\left(t^5\right)$$
$$\log \left(1+\sqrt{1+t}\right)=\log (2)+\frac{t}{4}-\frac{3 t^2}{32}+\frac{5 t^3}{96}-\frac{35
   t^4}{1024}+O\left(t^5\right)$$ Make $t=\frac 1{y^2}=\frac 1{a^2x^2}$ to get the desired result.